# NgIf if property is not undefined?

Tags: angular, angular8

There is a structure directive **ngIf**:

```
<tr *ngIf="p.taxbalance">
</tr>
```

Problem is that there is no property `taxbalance` in object `p`.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'taxbalance' of undefined

I tried to use this signature:

```
<tr *ngIf="p?.taxbalance"></tr>
```

But it does not work too

Comment: what do you mean by _But it does not work too_?

Comment: What about `p && p.taxbalance`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $any() type cast function

you can use the $any() cast function to cast the expression to the any type

```
<tr *ngIf="$any(p).taxbalance"></tr>
```

Comment: How is disabling type checking in the template supposed to solve a null object access error? Care to explain?

Comment: Can you check this:https://blog.angularindepth.com/type-checking-templates-in-angular-viewengine-and-ivy-77f8536359f5

Comment: Check this also for More info:https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/01/11/what-is-new-angular-5.2/